# How to Know If I've Correctly Inserted Alt Attributes Into HTML

Tags: html, seo

Apologies in advance - HTML isn't really my language and I'm new to Stack. Hope this is in the right place!

I'm working on inserting alt attributes for all the images on this WordPress website, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I'm used to doing things in the front end - not in HTML. Is there a resource that I can use to see if they're being read?

The visual page looks like this:

```
[content_boxes style="style6"][gta_tour_listing tourid="wachosl" alignment="left" image="httpS://geckotrail.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/howler-baby.jpg" alt="Howler Baby Southern Caribbean"]
```

The **text** page looks like this:

```
[content_boxes style="style6"] [gta_tour_listing tourid="wachosl" alignment="left" image="httpS://geckotrail.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/howler-baby.jpg" alt="Howler Baby Southern Caribbean"]
```

Comment: What is this code you added to your question? What happens when you call the site in your browser and inspect the source code? Are the alt attributes to your images being applied or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the source code from the front-end of your website, ie the published version of the page that your website visitors can see.

The code you're pasting here is *not* HTML. These are shortcodes that a plugin or the active in WordPress use to *generate* HTML.

The good news is you can very easily view the source of any website using your browser.

Here's [an exhaustive list of the way to do that with every major browser](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm).

When you can view the source, you can check your `<img>` tags for the alt text you've entered.

If that's too complex, you can always use one of the [myriad of alt tag testers available online](https://seositecheckup.com/tools/image-alt-test).